# auth0 token: Failed to compile

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-jwt

I've been learning Asp.net core and angular from scratch

I am watching a video. And i am sure that i'm following the instructions in the video.

I installed the library using npm

```
npm install @auth0/angular-jwt
```

Then i'm having this error

```
Failed to compile.

../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common/http' in 'C:\Users\dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DatingApp\node_modules\@auth0\angular-jwt'
```

What is the cause of it? i re watch the video thrice in order to find what's wrong but i can't solve it.

When i imported the `JwtHelperService` the intelisense of the editor i am using `pops up`. So im assuming that the JwtHelperService is installed properly.

i also added `jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();` variable

and created a method like this

```
loggedIn() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
}
```

But where does the error came from? How can i solve it?

Update:

Its giving me error when i add a variable

```
 jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
```

Regards,
Ramon

Comment: Is this a version conflict between angular-jwt and the version of angular you have installed?

Comment: Hello Kai. I installed 
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64

And i installed the angular-jwt 2.0.0

Is this a conflict?

Comment: No idea, but I would recommend checking what the peer dependency versions of angular-jwt are